# Split an irregular string into key-value pairs

Tags: c#, string, split

I have a string that is being submitted by our customers from an application on which I cannot put a validation on their end to restrict sending those kind of strings. So, I am trying to write a C# function to split the string into a key value pair / make sure the string matches a format so that the split into key value will be easy.

Here are my examples (ABCD is common in here) and the answer I get should be in the form of below for the examples

ABCD 1234 should be  --> ABCD-1234

ABCD  1234 (two or theree spaces in between) should be ABCD-1234

ABCD 1234 should be(starts with a space)  --> ABCD-1234

ABCD XX1234 should be  --> ABCD-XX1234

ABCD--Z1234 should be --> ABCD-Z1234

ABCDTE ST QA1234 should be --> ABCD-QA1234

A-BCD 1234 ABCD-1234

Also, if possible, I will need this as well integrated into the same function for the above.

ABCDE-GHI491803 Should be WXYZ-491803

ABCDEFGH CT542021 Should be WXYZ-CT542021

Comment: So you have requirements. Go implement them. What is your question?

Comment: Could you edit your post to include: (1) a clear rule for how to transform any input to the desired output and (2) a question? See [Writing The Perfect Question](http://tinyurl.com/stack-hints).

Comment: Otherwise only down-votes will answer you.

Comment: The _Infinite Number of Monkeys_ thank-you in giving them this opportunity to work on your question, in its infinite number of possibilities they might add.  Sadly however, they are unable to write code for you at the moment as they are rather busy working on their version of _Hamlet_.  What research have you done? What have you tried? These things will help us and the Monkeys help you.  Good luck!   _[How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)_

Answer (score 1):

for some of your requirements you can write extension method for string, for example:

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static string FormatMyString(this string input)
    {
        input = Regex.Replace(input, @"-+", " ");
        return Regex.Replace(input, @"\s+", " ").Replace(" ", "-");
    }
}
```

then in your code you can use it as follows:

```
var formatted = "ABCD-- 1234".FormatMyString();
```

but replacing letters...I don't see any logic there...how many beers did you have?

Comment: well played BeardedMan.